# mysql if statement with variable

Tags: mysql

I have this code:

```
$post = 0;
$rows = $wpdb->get_results( "select * from table where if('".$post."' != 0, id = '".$post."', id != 0) " );
```

If `$post` doesn't have value 0, I need to take all rows which have id `$post`, and if `$post` has id 0, I need to take all rows which don't have id 0, but it doesn't return any result

Comment: you will need ternary there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If statements can't be used to make parts of the query dynamic try this instead:

```
"select * from table where " . ($post ? "id = $post" : "id != 0")
```

This assumes that `$post` is not user supplied. If it is you will have to ensure it's a number and not malicious.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing :

```
$post = 0;

$rows = $wpdb->get_results( "select * from table where if('".$post."' != 0, id = '".$post."', id != 0) " );
```

First try to do in this way:

```
$sql = "select * from table where if('".$post."' != 0, id = '".$post."', id != 0)";

echo "$sql";
```

copy the out put and try to run it in your actual database manually. If it will show the result then it will work in your wp code also.

Thank you.